# What does this error mean in IBM Netezza Administrator? - ERROR: Permission denied on "_VT_DISK_PARTITION"

Tags: netezza, ibm-netezza-administrator

What does this error mean when opening IBM Netezza Administrator?

ERROR: Permission denied on "_VT_DISK_PARTITION"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked someone in my department, and I guess the tool always throws this error when you do not have administrator permissions.  That Netezza view (_VT_DISK_PARTITION) is not accessible with non-admin security.  It's necessary to show some of the features in the default view/tab ("System") of the tool.

When clicking on the "Database" view/tab, and navigate to some database and table, it might take a bit to load the data.  But that view/tab should not throw any errors to make the tool usable.

[image]